# Equivalent of std::iota in java

Tags: java, stl

I want to port this C++ code which use `std::iota` into Java.

```cpp
std::array<int, 10> ar;
std::iota(ar.begin(), ar.end(), -4);

for(const auto value: ar) {
  ...
```

which will create an array `ar` of int filled by `{-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5}`

Currently I'm using the following code, but I'm looking for something simpler (and if possible without third party):

```java
import com.google.common.collect.ContiguousSet;
import com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain;
import com.google.common.collect.Range;
...
ContiguousSet<Integer> ar =
  ContiguousSet.create(
    Range.closedOpen(-4, 6),  
    DiscreteDomain.integers());

for (int value : ar) {
  ...
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

src: STL `std::iota`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Comment: Why the downvotes? Unless it was edited later, it looks like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

According to QBrute I could use.

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

int[] ar = IntStream.range(-4, 6).toArray()

for (int value : ar) {
  ...
  System.out.println(value);
}
```

src: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `IntStream.range(-4, 6)` which you can then collect to a set. It's a Java built-in and it doesn't rely on 3rd party libraries.

Comment: basically I just want to fill a `List<Integer>` or a `int[]`

Comment: `List<Integer> l = IntStream.range(-4, 6).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())` or `int[] array = IntStream.range(-4, 6).toArray()`